# $F\cup G \le V$ if and only if $F \subseteq G$ or $G\subseteq F$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In an exercise I'm asked to prove the following result:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $F,G \le V$. Prove that $F\cup G \le V$ if and only if $F \subseteq G$ or $G\subseteq F$.

I was able to prove that $F \subseteq G \vee G\subseteq F \to F\cup G \le V$ But I'm not being able to prove the opposite.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are elements $x\in F\setminus G$ and $y\in G\setminus F$ then $x+y$ is a sum of elements in $F\cup G$, and since by assumption this is a subspace we have $x+y\in F\cup G$. So $x+y\in F$ or $x+y\in G$. Let's assume $x+y\in F$. Then, since $F$ is a subspace:

$y=(x+y)-x\in F$

But this in a contradiction, because $y\in G\setminus F$. Similarly, if $x+y\in G$ then:

$x=(x+y)-y\in G$

Which is again a contradiction, because $x\in F\setminus G$.